# Rails scope with method value comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope

So i'm fairly new to rails and `ActiveRecord` and I have a need for a scope to filter between `Client` entities. Basically the scope should return all `Client` records where the client's current state is equal to a certain state object.

This is calculated by getting a client's last `state_change` and then pulling that `state_change`'s `from_state` which is a `State` object.

I have defined a method to return the `current_state` however in rails console when I test it with `Client.current_state(Client.last)` I get this error:

`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'state_changes for #<Class:0x0000000685eb88>` but when running `Client.last.state_changes` in console it works fine.

My client.rb

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many               :users
  belongs_to                            :industry
  belongs_to                            :account
  has_many                              :contacts
  has_many                              :state_changes
  belongs_to                            :head,          class_name: "Client"
  has_many                              :branches,      class_name: "Client", foreign_key: "head_id"
  has_many                              :meetings,      through: :contacts
  has_many                              :sales,         through: :meetings

  scope :prospects, -> (client) { where(Client.current_state(client): State.PROSPECT_STATE) }

  def self.has_at_least_one_sale? (client)
    return client.sales.empty?
  end

  def self.has_account_number? (client)
    return client.account_number.present?
  end

  def self.current_state (client)
    state_changes.last.to_state
  end
end
```

state_change.rb

```
class StateChange < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :from_state,   class_name: "State", foreign_key: :to_state_id
  belongs_to :to_state,     class_name: "State", foreign_key: :from_state_id
end
```

state.rb

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :from_states,    class_name: "StateChange", foreign_key: :to_state_id
  has_many :to_states,      class_name: "StateChange", foreign_key: :from_state_id

  def self.PROSPECT_STATE
    return State.find_by name: 'Prospect'
  end

  def self.CLIENT_STATE
    return State.find_by name: 'Client'
  end

  def self.SUSPECT_STATE
    return State.find_by name: 'Suspect'
  end
end
```

I also get syntax errors regarding the scope I defined in client.rb. I have followed the `ActiveRecord` guide but they don't explain how to have chained methods in the actualy scope query.

Comment: I suggest you to read [Class and Instance Methods in Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get the error `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'state_changes for #<Class:0x0000000685eb88>` is because you define `current_state` as a class method and pass the client as a parameter. That's why `state_changes` is called on the class and not the instance. In this case you would need to use the client to get the `state_changes`.

```
def self.current_state (client)
  client.state_changes.last.to_state
end
```

Also scopes are meant to just chain query logic. I'm not sure if it is possible to just use queries to get your wanted result. And I hope I understood your logic correctly. Alternatively you could use a class method.

```
def self.prospects (client)
  Client.all.select { |c| c.current_state(c) == State.PROSPECT_STATE }
end
```

As pointed out by Зелёный in the comment, maybe you also want to just change the methods to instance methods, in which case reading the resource he linked would be very helpful.

Update based on comment:

I think what you actually want is using an instance method for `current_state` like this:

```
def current_state
  state_changes.last.to_state
end
```

And then you can get prospects like this:

```
def self.prospects
  Client.all.select { |c| c.current_state == State.PROSPECT_STATE }
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure if I understand why you'd want a parameter for `self.prospects`, the idea of that is to simply return every client that has the prospect_state

Comment: `Client.all.select { |c| Client.current_state(c) == State.PROSPECT_STATE }` is what worked. Thank you! And I did read that resource.

Comment: @barnacle.m this is gonna be such a drag on the speed, you should look into query method instead of using `ruby` `select`